# importing different bridging header between multiple target

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watch

I have two target on for **watch OS** and without watch.
I have to import **briding header** as under. Message util has been added to both target. but it is giving compiler **error** as

> "Use of undeclared identifier MessageUtil".

```
#import "SomeClass.h"

#ifdef TARGET_OS_WATCH
#import "Watch-Header.h"
#import "With_Watch-Swift.h"
#elif TARGET_OS_IOS
#import "Without_Watch-Header.h"
#import "Without_Watch-Swift.h"
#endif

@implementation SomeClass

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.message = [MessageUtil messageOne];//MessageUtil is swift class.
    }
    return self; }

@end
```

Comment: What is set for target of `SomeClass`?

Comment: ComeClass has multiple targets.

Comment: Try removing everything from `#ifdef` to `#endif` and importing either one of the `"With_Watch-Swift.h"` and `"Without_Watch-Swift"` where the `MessageUtil` is exposed to.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Though my requirement import based on target.

Answer (score 0):

You could create additional `Bridging-Header.h` for other targets and then simply specify newly created Bridging Header location in `Build Settings -> Objective-C Bridging Header`.

[image]